# DOTNET: How to condense multiple commands into one

Tags: .net

in node js we have package.json and all we need to do is add a custom script like:

```
"scripts": {
      "start": "node src/index.js",
}
```

Is there a dotnet equivalent to scripts? I am using docker and I don't want to run docker down and back up etc all the time. thanks.

Comment: just use a docker file. that we you can specify all the env variables and other parameters you want to pass to your container.  that is how i use docker.

Comment: I need to start up docker, but before doing that i need to do docker down on everything. and to upload to cloud i would need to do 3 different commands including docker. i need a way to create script that does all that with one command.